# Having a hard time getting the value of <select> element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select, each

HTML:

```
.....
<form id="manage">
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input class="required" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />

    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input class="required" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />

    <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
    <select class="required" name="gender" id="gender">
        <option selected value="m">Male</option>
        <option value="f">Female</option>
        <option value="u">Undecided</option>
    </select>
</form>
.....
```

jQuery:

```
.....
$("#manage .required").each( function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        alert($(this).attr("id") + " is empty!"); // Code for debugging
        $(this).prev().addClass("error");
        is_error = true;
    }
});
.....
```

In the above simple code snippet, I am trying to add the `error` class to any of the elements within the `<form>` if its value is empty.

The problem is, the `$(this).attr("id")` is not picking up the `<select>` element for some reason; I get the alert for both `first_name` and `last_name` but not for the `gender` id. I've been stuck on this seemingly trivial issue for hours now but can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

I probably just need a good slap on the face but any non-violent help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nothing to do with `$(this).attr('id')`, it is because your selection doesn't have an  option with value `""`, its default value is `m`.

Try adding one:

```
 <select class="required" name="gender" id="gender">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="m">Male</option>
    <option value="f">Female</option>
    <option value="u">Undecided</option>
</select>
```

And on a side note you could use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` and `this.id` instead of  `$(this).attr('id')`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxQ3P/)**

Comment: @Vivendi75 In other words, your original `select` has a default value of `"male"` and not `""`.

Comment: @PSL - I completely understand what you explained here. In fact, I had the same thought as you did - and I would expect the `if` statement block to NOT get executed for `select` since none of the options holds an empty value. But, that doesn't seem to be the case. I still get an alert for `select` but it comes up as `(undefined) is empty!`.

Comment: @Vivendi75 for that you need to do a `return false` to exit out of the loop. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/jdzbw/

Comment: @PSL - I figured out with your help, thanks a lot! (+1 for the side note)